# How to get all unique elements which didn't duplicated in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array which has duplicated values and I want to filter that array with the only unique elements. All values which have been duplicated or occurring more than 1 times should be excluded

Example: I have an array x which has these values

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
```

Expected Result is

```
[1, 4]
```

Comment: I'd feed it into a Set.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I try that, but still not as expected. Use Set will return [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: @Fallenreaper `Set` will not get the expected output. OP wants to completely remove duplicates. In other words you can say that he wants to only those elements which occur once.

Comment: Use `reduce` to create an object which has array elements as keys and values as its count and then you can apply filter whose values are equal to one. `const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]; const groupByOccurence = x.reduce((accu, ele) => {accu[ele] = (accu[ele] || 0) + 1; return accu;}, {});console.log(Object.entries(groupByOccurence).filter(([_, val]) => val == 1).map(([key, _]) => +key));`

Comment: Oops, yeah, i didnt see the delete, i thought it was "Remove Duplicates".  Since it is marked a duplicate, I cant give my answer, so i would suggest looking at that other thread.